# Best way to store a huge list with hashes in Javascript

Tags: javascript, list, object

I have a list with 10.000 entrys.

**for example**

```
myList = {};
myList[hashjh5j4h5j4h5j4]
myList[hashs54s5d4s5d4sd]
myList[hash5as465d45ad4d]
....
```

I dont use an array (0,1,2,3) because i can check
very fast 
 -> if this hash exist or not.

```
if(typeof myObject[hashjh5j4h5j4h5j4] == 'undefined')
{
  alert('it is new'); 
}
else
{
  alert('old stuff'); 
}
```

But i am not sure, is this a good solution? 
Is it maybe a problem to handle an object with 10.000 entries?

**EDIT:**
I try to build an rss feed reader which shows only new feeds. So i calculate an hash from the link (every news has an uniqe link) and store it in the object (mongoDB). BTW: 10.000 entrys is not the normal case (but it is possible)

Comment: Please tell us what you are trying to accomplish, as it will shape the kind of suggestions you get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My advice:

1. Use as small of a hash as possible for the task at hand. If you are dealing with hundreds of hashable strings, compared to billions, then your hash length can be relatively small.
2. Store the hash as an integer, not a string, to avoid making it take less room than needed.
3. Don't store as objects, just store them in a simple binary tree log2(keySize) deep.

Further thoughts:

1. Can you come at this with a hybrid approach? Use hashes for recent feeds less than a month old, and don't bother showing items more than a month old. Store the hash and date together, and clean out old hashes each day?

Comment: I cant save "binary tree logs" in the MongoDb but your further thoughts are interesting. I must (go away by myself and) think about that in peace and quiet.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `in` operator:

```
if ('hashjh5j4h5j4h5j4' in myList) { .. }
```

However, this will also return `true` for members that are in the objects prototype chain:

```
Object.prototype.foo = function () {};
if ("foo" in myList) { /* will be true */ };
```

To fix this, you could use [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) instead:

```
if (myList.hasOwnProperty('hashjh5j4h5j4h5j4')) { .. }
```

Whilst you yourself may not have added methods to `Object.prototype`, you cannot guarantee that other 3rd party libraries you use haven't; incidentally, extending `Object.prototype` is frowned upon, so you shouldn't really do it. **Why?**; because you shouldn't modify things you don't own.

Answer (score 2):

10.000 is quite a lot. You may consider storing the hashes in a database and query it using ajax. It maybe takes a bit longer to query one hash but your page loads much faster.

Comment: +1. The **problem** here will not be storing the 10,000 objects in an Object, the problem will be the ***size*** of the page containing the 10,000 objects, and the time taken to transfer them.

Comment: maybe the hashcodes will generate on the client side and not needs to transfer.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a problem in modern browser on modern computers in any way.

10k entries that take up 50 bytes each would still take up less than 500KB ram.

As long as the js is served gzipped then bandwidth is no problem - but do try to serve the data as late as possible so they don't block perceived pageload performance.

All in all, unless you wish to cater to cellphones then your solution is fine.

Comment: But if there is a better way to be more efficient, it couldn't hurt.

Comment: True, and the solution can certainly be optimized quite a bit. However the approach in itself is fine, and there is no problem for a modern browser to handle 10k properties on an object.